# Unable to connect Eclipse IDE with hana cloud trial account

Tags: eclipse, hana

I am trying to connect SAP HANA trial account with eclipse IDE

I am using a direct internet connection with following settings :

I am using the same credentials (emailID and password when logging into HANA cockpit). I am not sure what am I doing wrong here.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QXtrU.png]
  [image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jRlX1.png]

Answer (score 3):

1. your account name should be the same as you wrote but you have to add "trial" suffix to it
2. your username is the same as your account name just you should exclude "trial" suffix.

according to your screenshot it should be like this

1. account name : p1940990208trial
2. user name : p1940990208

Answer (score 1):

You've specified p1940990208 as account name (visible in the second screen shot), while in reality your account is p1940990208**trial**. Please fix that and try it out again - I'm pretty sure it's gonna work fine.

Best wishes,
  Krassi

Comment: I tried entering my email id as account name and it worked just fine. Thanks for the reply :)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem - the instructions on the SAP site are a bit confusing. When you add in the details on the first screen it is your accountID with the trial suffix and then your account id plus the password associated with it. Once you have authenticated then you use the database user you set up to the database.